# I want data for customers for last three months from there deactivation date So I joined two

Tags: sql, db2-400

I want  data for customers for last three months from there deactivation date

So I joined two tables
One table have data like recharge, Report_Month
Other table have deactivation date

Both table have mobile number column
So I have condition in where clause
Disconnection date between 2019-05-07 and 2019-08-10

And 
Report month between ?????

So I have trouble in Report month condition

Report month data like 1,2,3 upto 12

So I want data between disconnection date and before three months of disconnection date

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data presented as a table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question, I think you're asking how to select the last three months worth of data from a disconnection date. If so you'll need a condition like:

```
WHERE `Report_Month` >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, `Disconnection_date`)
```

So this will return everything with a report month up to three months before disconnection date.

The second part confuses me more, I think you're asking to group the report month, up to 12 months, but, if you're only retrieving the last three months data, then how could you group by 12?

```
GROUP BY Year(`Report_Month`), Month(`Report_Month`)
ORDER BY Year(`Report_Month`), Month(`Report_Month`)
```

That will group your results by Month in order, if that's what you're after?